# ProgressDialog crashing in onPreExecute

Tags: java, android

I get a crash "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" in a onPreExecute in a thread. It was my understanding that onPreExecute runs on the UI Thread, so how can it crash?

```
public void onPreExecute() {
        if (loading == null || !loading.isShowing())
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(co, "",
                    "Retrieving Geolocation...", true);
    }
```

Quite strangely, it works sometimes, and sometimes not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AsyncTask` Threading rules](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (few paragraphs down) state:

- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
- execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
- Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
- The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

My guess is that you called `execute()` on background thread.

Comment: I possible execute twice. Will check that.

Answer (score 0):

From your question looks like you are using `onPreExecute()` in a thread.

`onPreExecute()` is a method in `AsyncTask` class provided by android. If you override it , then it will ensure that that code runs on UI thread, not just `onPreExecute()` anywhere in your code!
A good idea is to always use `@Override` notation when you are overriding a method, that way IDE will notify you about if any method for overriding with given signature is there or not...

Comment: I didnt start onPreExecute from my code. Android starts it correctly when I execute the thread